# User cannot change password using devise in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise in my rails application. I have defined some roles for users using the rolify gem.

Only Managers can signup and after signup, can create his own assistant and supervisors. When a manager creates a supervisor or assistant, an email notification is sent to them with credentials.

Problem is that only managers can change their passwords, but other roles are not, without an error message.

How do I make it so that any role can change their password?

```
def settings_save
    if params[:user][:assistant] == "0"
      current_user.remove_role "assistant" if current_user.has_role? :assistant
      assistants_ = current_user.company.assistants      
      assistants_.each do |assistant|
        assistant.assistant = false        
        if assistant.save(validate:false)
          assistant.remove_role "assistant"
        end
      end
      params[:assistants_email].each do |m|        
        next if m.blank?          
          if User.where(email: m).first.nil?
            password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
            user = User.new(company_id:current_user.company_id, email: m, password: password, assistant:true)
            if user.save(validate:false)
              user.add_role "assistant"
              UserMailer.new_assistant(user,password,current_user).deliver
            end
          else
            user = User.where(email: m).first
            user.assistant = true
            if user.save(validate:false)
              user.add_role "assistant"
            end
            #flash[:notice] = "Email Already Exists" 
            # redirect_to :back 
          end
      end
    else
      current_user.add_role "assistant"
      assistant = current_user.company.assistant.where('email !=?', current_user.email)

      assistants.each do |u|
        #u.email += rand(5..30).to_s
        u.marketer = false
        if u.save(validate: false)
          u.remove_role "assistant"
        end 
      end
    end
```

And here is password change view

> 

```
<div class="col-xs-5 signup_container">
  <h2>Change your password</h2>

  <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: password_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-fields-aligned-error">
      <%= f.error_notification %>
    </div>

    <%= f.input :reset_password_token, as: :hidden %>
    <%= f.full_error :reset_password_token %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :password, label: "New password", required: true, autofocus: true %>
      <%= f.input :password_confirmation, label: "Confirm your new password", required: true %>
    </div>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.button :submit, "Change my password" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
</div>
```

Through above code a signup manager can create his assistant and it is working fine, the user is created successfully and I can login with these user credentials.  However, I can't change password for this user.

Comment: please include some code snippets of the included parts in this operation.

Comment: @NafaaBoutefer code updated please.

Comment: I mean code that changes the password.

Comment: i am using devise.There is no controller action just using devise view.code updated

Comment: try the #solution 2# here [How To: Allow users to edit their password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)